# Auto update/pull docker image on GCP Instance Groups with Container-Optimized OS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-container-os

I have a instance on GCP running in **Instance Group** with a **Container-Optimized OS** using a single image hosted on GCR.

**I want to pull a new image to GCP, and refresh the instance image with that new image.** I'm building and pushing over GitHub Actions and can call some `gcloud` command inside the CI workflow.

I want to say "hey Instance Group, do pull again the container imagens". It would be good to do this keeping the service running.

What should be the best approach to do that? What full `gcloud` command to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The steps are:

1. Prepare a new Docker image.
2. [Create an instance template based upon the new Docker image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates/create-instance-templates#with-container).
3. [Update the MIG](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/rolling-out-updates-to-managed-instance-groups#starting_a_basic_rolling_update) (Managed Instance Group).

**Create an instance template:**

```
gcloud compute instance-templates create-with-container [TEMPLATE_NAME] --container-image [DOCKER_IMAGE]
```

**Update the MIG:**

```
gcloud compute instance-groups managed rolling-action start-update [MIG_NAME] --version template=[TEMPLATE_NAME]
```

You can read more about configuring the available options for your update [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/rolling-out-updates-to-managed-instance-groups#options).

Comment: It need create a new template to each deployed version? That's sounds odd, but seams to work.

Comment: @TiagoGouvêa Yes, you need to create a new instance template. Managed instance groups are immutable. You can cheat if you use the same docker image tag name and then do a rolling-action replace. I do not recommend that strategy except for testing

Answer (score 3):

I had the same question. For anyone coming across it in the future, an additional solution to the rolling action replace is to use the `gcloud beta compute instances update-container` command.

The documentation can be found here
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/instances/update-container

Here's their example:

```
gcloud beta compute instances update-container instance-1 --zone us-central1-a --container-image=gcr.io/google-containers/busybox
```

In the case of automation you would need to know an instance name and have an image in the registry

Answer (score 2):

For future reference the following command updates all the instances of an instance group in GCP. Here i used my instance group name "app-backend-instance-group" in the zone "europe-west3-c". Please replace those values.

```
for i in $(gcloud compute instances list --filter NAME~"app-backend-instance-group" --format="value(NAME)");do gcloud beta compute instances update-container $i --zone europe-west3-c --container-image=gcr.io/deployments-337523/app-backend:latest;done
```